# Problema em concatenar usando jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho o seguinte exemplo que não consigo fazer.

Tenho uma div:

```
<div class="dados" data-attribute="2" onclick="bloquearSacado(1,2);">
       <p>Teste</p>
        </div>
```

E tenho o seguinte código:

```
status = 3;
codigo = 8;
$('.dados[data-attribute='+ id + ']').attr('onclick',(status+, id));
```

Quando eu executo esse código ele soma os valores 1+8 porém eu preciso que fique assim:

```
 onclick="bloquearSacado(3,8);"
```

Qual a maneira certa de concatenar nessa situação de modo que fique igual ao de resultado de cima?

PS: o ( e , são fundamentais.

Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Apresente o código, fica mais fácil de mostrar o problema do que tentando explicar e ainda teremos um [MCVE]

Comment: Mas eu apresentei o codigo: é uma div <div class="dados" data-attribute="2" onclick="bloquearSacado(1,2);">
       <p>Teste</p>
        </div>

Comment: Que eu executo o codigo $('.dados[data-attribute='+ id + ']').attr('onclick',(status+, id));   com variaveis status = 2 e id = 9 e ele soma os dois valores no onclick e não CONCATENA, entendeu?

Comment: Onde a variável `codigo` entra nisso?

Comment: Acho que vc colocou o código errado. Seria isso: `$('.dados[data-attribute='+ id + ']').attr('onclick','bloquearSacado('+status+','+codigo+')');`

Comment: E não faz muito sentido você ter um evento onClick e querer fazer o bind de outro pelo seletor... apresente o código

Answer (score 5):

Seu problema começa em erro de sintaxe:

```
(status+, id)
```

Essa vírgula após o `+` causa erro pois não tem como somar ou concatenar duas variáveis com uma vírgula no meio.

Se quer alterar o atributo do elemento com as duas variáveis `status` e `codigo`, o correto seria colocar também o nome da função e alterar os valores dentro dos parêntesis concatenando os valores fora das aspas do método:

```
$('.dados[data-attribute='+ id + ']').attr('onclick','bloquearSacado('+status+','+codigo+')');
```